# Netty Decoder for specific Xml Tags

Tags: java, xml, tcp, client-server, netty

I'm trying to make a TCP server using netty that runs a TCP Server, listens for incoming xml strings and sends any received xml to all open Connections.

The xml is always formatted the same way (beginning and ending with ).

In addition to handling it's own server connections, it also open a connection with a second server that does the same thing and pools all xml between the two.
So basically there's a ServerBootstrap that listens for incoming XML data from any Connection that it listens for as well as one pre-defined connection that the application manages itself.

The two major issues I'm having is

a.) properly listening for data and deliminating incoming strings based on the xml tag.
I've tried using XmlDecoder in my pipeline but that doesn't seem to be doing anything. In fact my ServerBootstrap just ends without doing anything, is it supposed to block for listening purposes?

Here's my Server Bootstrap

```
try {
    ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap()
            .group(listenGroup, speakingGroup)
            .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
            .localAddress(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", mListeningPort))
            .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                @Override
                protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                    ch.pipeline()
                            //.addLast("string-decoder", new StringDecoder())
                            .addLast("xml-decoder", new XmlDecoder())
                            .addLast(new ServerHandler());
                }
            });            
    ChannelFuture channelFuture = bootstrap.bind().syncUninterruptibly();
} finally {
    listenGroup.shutdownGracefully();
    speakingGroup.shutdownGracefully();
}
```

The other issue im having is establishing a connection to the mirror server and adding it to the list of outputs for the ServerBootstrap. I've done less testing on this myself, and theoretically an interface leading back to a regular ol' Bootstrap should work, but I'm not sure how to keep the Bootstrap connection alive or whether or not it's better to take the Channel somehow and add it to the ServerBootstraps group.

Any thoughts? Sorry if it's a little confusing what i'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that your parenthesis that you are using to delimit your messages isn't supported by the xml decoder.  (i.e. you aren't actually sending valid xml)  Is there a reason that you can't just use an outermost xml group that holds the entire message?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by that? Is there a special group that handles xml?

EDIT: To clarify, I've tried StringDecoder as well as XmlDecoder, but I'm actually not getting any data at all. I assumed it was because it's waiting for xmls and ignoring everything else.